# How do I create a pre-op clearcase trigger that prevents delivery to a specific stream

Tags: clearcase-ucm

I have worked with ClearCase triggers in the past but it have been over ten years ago.

I want to make a pre-op trigger which prevents a delivery to a specific stream except for specific users.

I know I can use `nusers` to allow only certain users to bypass the trigger, but with the `opkind` do I specify deliver or deliver_start?

For identifying the specific stream, do I write a Perl script that checks for the name, or is there a way I can use the restriction-list or the inclusion-list?

Answer (score 0):

This "[Delivery preoperation trigger script](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/rational-clearcase/8.0.1?topic=operations-delivery-preoperation-trigger-script)" is an official example which could give you some clues on how to write your own (in Perl).

You can see in it how its gets the stream name

```perl
use Config;

my $PVOBTAG;
my $tempfile;
my $exit_value;

if ($Config{'osname'} eq 'MSWin32') {
   $PVOBTAG = '\cyclone-pvob';
   $tempfile = $ENV{TMP}."\\expreop.".$ENV{"CLEARCASE_PPID"}.".txt";
}
else {
   $PVOBTAG = '';
}

my $STREAM = "stream:".$ENV{"CLEARCASE_STREAM"};
my $ATTYPE = "attype:deliver_in_progress\@$PVOBTAG";

print $STREAM."\n";
print $ATTYPE."\n";
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to show me examples of the mktrtype and mktrigger for this problem

Comment: @Bob I don't have much beside the setup script, which does show how mktrtype is done: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/rational-clearcase/8.0.1?topic=operations-delivery-setup-script